# How to call a function that fills all table columns with random values?

Tags: sql, oracle, function, random, plsql

I have created a function called customers_data tha returns random values in the customers table.
As far everthing compiled successfully. But when i call this

```
DECLARE

X_C NUMBER NOT NULL :=5 ;
Y_C NUMBER NOT NULL :=8 ;

BEGIN 

 FOR LOOP_COUNTER IN X_C..Y_C LOOP

   select * into CUSTOMERS from CUSTOMERS_DATA;

 END LOOP;

END;
```

THE ERROR IS:

```
ORA-06550
```

AND THE CUSTOMERS_DATA FUNCTION :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  CUSTOMERS_DATA

RETURN NUMBER AS CR_ID NUMBER;

   BEGIN

      CR_ID := CUSTOMERS_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL;

     INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS(CUSTOMERS_ID, CUSTOMERS_CODE )

          VALUES(CR_ID, dbms_random.string('X',10));

     
     RETURN CR_ID;

     
END CUSTOMERS_DATA;
```

Comment: you did not define a variable named `customers` so the `into` clause can't work

Comment: Additionally, how does the CUSTOMERS_DATA look like? FROM clause depends on it.

Comment: Why don't you include the error message? Nobody knows all error codes by heart, help us help you

Comment: @Littlefoot THAT'S CUSTOMERS_DATA CODE

Comment: Function with side effects (except, maybe, logging) is quite misleading design in naming convention especially when you do not use the returned value. What you really need here is a procedure and [`forall` instead of `loop`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-optimization-and-tuning.html#GUID-6D4A1425-64DD-4723-8AAE-87B0A51A2854) to avoid practicing in bad code design.

Comment: What about actual question: you cannot select *from* an [*expression*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Function-Expressions.html#GUID-C47F0B7D-9058-481F-815E-A31FB21F3BD5). A function call in Oracle is expression (except `sql_macro`): [*User-defined functions can appear in a SQL statement wherever an expression can occur*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/About-User-Defined-Functions.html#GUID-4EB3E236-8216-471C-BA44-23D87BDFEA67)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, it looks as if you wanted to run this:

Function:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CUSTOMERS_DATA
  2     RETURN NUMBER
  3  AS
  4     CR_ID  NUMBER;
  5  BEGIN
  6     CR_ID := CUSTOMERS_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
  7
  8     INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS (CUSTOMERS_ID, CUSTOMERS_CODE)
  9          VALUES (CR_ID, DBMS_RANDOM.string ('X', 10));
 10
 11     RETURN CR_ID;
 12  END CUSTOMERS_DATA;
 13  /

Function created.
```

PL/SQL block:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     X_C   NUMBER NOT NULL := 5;
  3     Y_C   NUMBER NOT NULL := 8;
  4     l_id  NUMBER;
  5  BEGIN
  6     FOR LOOP_COUNTER IN X_C .. Y_C
  7     LOOP
  8        l_id := customers_data;
  9     END LOOP;
 10  END;
 11  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Result:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM customers;

CUSTOMERS_ID CUSTOMERS_CODE
------------ --------------------
           1 465MT9ECDL
           2 4TY1QS8S75
           3 VNN0ZVP12W
           4 HSP5RIQSIE

SQL>
```

Comment: it retunrn me the same error in the pl/sql block. Underlined the customers_data. ora-06550

Comment: It shouldn't, because - as you can see, code I posted *works* with no errors.

Comment: it runs. thank you!